# QT QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I have 2 threads which each create a new `QTcpSocket` in the run `method()`.
I connect the two threads together widh a signal/slot like:

```
connect(thread1, SIGNAL(foo()), thread2, SLOT(bar()));
```

But when I want to use the socket from thread2 in bar slot I keep getting this error message:

```
"QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread"
```

Additional info:

- thread1 and thread2 are both objects of the same class.
- I used qDebug to check if the socket from bar slot is really the socket from thread2 (it is).

I want to know if anyone knows what am I doing wrong and why.

Thank you,
qwerty

Comment: You're trying to use a `QSocketNotifier` that exists on one thread from a different thread.  To diagnose the problem any further you'll need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: As @G.M. states, an MCVE will much improve your questions, as at present, we can only guess as to what is wrong. It sounds like you're inheriting from `QThread`. I suggest following the method as outlined in [this article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

Comment: Ok, I will try to provide a MCVE later today, thanks for answer so far.